# cast property inside linq where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of buttons inside  `CanvasClock.Children.OfType<Button>()`. Now I want to get all the button whose `tag` property contains `IsHour` field as `true`.

```
  var btn = CanvasClock.Children.OfType<Button>().Select(x => x.Tag as ButtonTag).Where(x => x.IsHour == true);
```

I have tried as shown above, but this gives me a list of `ButtonTag` instead of Button. How can I get the list of `Button` itself.

Comment: `Where(z => (z.Tag as ButtonTag)?.IsHour == true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `ButtonTag` type inside `Where` clause using [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern), without mapping to another type in `Select` method

```cs
var btn = CanvasClock.Children.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Tag is ButtonTag buttonTag && buttonTag.IsHour);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think there was anything wrong with Mong Zhu's answer, but it's now deleted

If you know absolutely for certain that all the buttons on the list have a tag and it's always a ButtonTag, you can just straight cast and retrieve the hour

```
.Where(x => ((ButtonTag)x.Tag).IsHour)
```

Only you will know whether it is always the case that everything in the list is a Button with a ButtonTag in its Tag. If it is not always the case, look at something like Pavel's answer, especially if (in the future) someone might add some code that suddenly means the tags aren't always ButtonTags

To understand why your original attempt went wrong you have to appreciate that Select typically creates new kinds of objects from your list of original objects and, unless there is a way to retrieve the original object from the new you've lost the original object.

Your select pulled out just the ButtonTag, so unless this class type has a reference to the button that once owned it (for example a ParentButton property that refers to the button the tag is assigned to) you can't retrieve the original object any more

If you're in a situation like that, you can do as all the solutions suggest here, that the casting is done in the where (because Where just returns original objects that satisfy a condition, I.e it returns Buttons) or you can consider making it so the Select returns the original object as well as any new things you're creating:

```
.Select(x => new { OriginalButton = x, ButtonTag = (ButtonTag)x.Tag })
```

This prepares a new anonymous type with our derived/calculated/new info as well as the original info that drove it

You probably wouldn't do this in this case, because it's so trivial as to not need it, but you might one day be faced with needing to return all the original info about an object plus some new stuff you calculated and a simple way to do that is to include the original as a property along with the new stuff via something like this

Answer (score 0):

By using Select u are casting ur Button to ButtonTag which u don't need.
u need to **filter** ur result not **alternate**
where is **filter**
select is **alternator**
so u need where

```
 var allHourBtns = CanvasClock.Children.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Tag is ButtonTag buttonTag && buttonTag.IsHour);
```